# reading an array of character (String) in java

Tags: java, string

I am trying to solve a problem with Java and the input is a string of 15 characters for example. when I use a `scanner` to read it using the method `nextLine()` it doesn't work because the input string doesn't have a `\n` in the end
for example the input is :

```
15 3
cccaabababaccbc
```

my code :

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
int n = s.nextInt();
int k = s.nextInt();
String temp = s.nextLine();
temp = s.next();
```

note that I read the temp twice to get the `\n` in the end of the first line.the problem link and my submission is 
[here](http://codeforces.com/contest/999/submission/39501858)

Comment: I don't understand your problem. Do you have issues reading from user input or for traversing the characters in the String?

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't work?

Comment: i mean it just produces a runtime error because it waits too much to get to the end of the string but simply it doesn't end with \n

Comment: If you want to read 15 `char`s, read `char`s and not lines (which are `String`s).

Comment: look it the edit i'v provided my submission

Comment: Turing85  you mean character by character? how is that ?

Comment: E.g. [`InputStreamReader#read(char[], int, int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/io/InputStreamReader.html#read(char%5B%5D,int,int)).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scanner is skipping nextLine() after using next() or nextFoo()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/scanner-is-skipping-nextline-after-using-next-or-nextfoo)

Answer (score 0):

You can read two numbers with nextInt() and then read string with only next() - it should work fine. Scanner next() will ignore whitespaces - see the init string in my example.

```
public static void main(String [] args){
   Scanner scanner = new Scanner("3 5 \n abcdef    z");
   System.out.println(scanner.nextInt());
   System.out.println(scanner.nextInt());
   System.out.println(scanner.next());
   System.out.println(scanner.next());
}
```

it gives me result

```
3
5
abcdef
z
```